# how to use sleep() in GTK+

Tags: c++, gtk, cairo

I'm making an app to read cards and then print its balance, when user wants to see his balance he clicks on Balance Enquiry button on main screen. I've created the background using Cairo. Now when user click `Balance Enquiry` the screen showing `show your card` should be paused for 2-3 seconds, So I'm using sleep() function. But the problem is the screen sleeps on click on `Bal. Enq.` button, I'm sure that the `sleep()` is  after the code that prints `show ur card` on screen.

Comment: The `sleep` function puts the whole thread to sleep, meaning no code in the thread runs at all. You should look for some other timeout mechanism.

Comment: Thank You for the quick response!!! There's a function `g_timeout_add_seconds` but it only allow particular type of function pointer inside it, and no regular function.

Comment: The function you pass to `g_timeout_add_seconds()` takes a pointer as an argument; if you have more than one piece of data, you should allocate a structure and pass it as the `user_data` argument of `g_timeout_add_seconds()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't use `sleep()` in a GTK+ GUI application, it will block the entire application and make it unresponsive. It is your application that causes GTK+ to do the work to update the interface; if you sleep, you stop GTK+ from running and thus the UI changes won't happen until the application wakes back up.

Look into glib's timeout API: [`g_timeout_add()`](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add) is a sensible place to start.

Comment: Thank You for quick answer I'll try this and accept your answer as soon as it starts to work.